# BibTex: modify alpha style: replace the comma between author and pages wt backslah

Tags: bibtex, cite-package

I am writing my bachelor thesis with LaTeX,  and my prof wants me to make the citation call-outs look like this:

> [Hei28/619–636]

I am using the bibstyle `alpha`, and unfortunately I don't know how to modify the style. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=4cm,bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{cite}
```

I use BibTeX. Here is a sample entry:

```
@article{heisenberg1928theorie,
title={Zur Theorie des Ferromagnetismus},
author={Heisenberg, Werner},
journal={Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Physik},
volume={49},
number={9--10},
pages={619--636},
year={1928},
publisher={Springer}
}
```

document itself

```
\begin{document}

Heisenberg is the Shit! Look at \cite[619--636]{heisenberg1928theorie}.

\bibliography{references} 

\end{document}
```

So right now the citation call-out looks like this:

> [Hei28, 619–636]

If anyone has an helpful advice on how to replace the comma and blank space with a (forward) slash, I really would appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document with bib (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography), not just a fragment.

Comment: The `ngerman` package is rather deprecated. Try loading the `babel` package with the option `ngerman` instead.

Comment: Incidentally, when a page (or page range) is mentioned in the citation call-out, it should refer to the actual passage from which something is cited, not the article's entire page range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case, the separator is stored in the `\citemid` macro as `,\penalty \citemidpenalty \`, which roughly translates to `,`.

You just have to redefine it:

```
\renewcommand{\citemid}{/}
```